# JAVA - Adding a comma after every two words in a String?

Tags: java, android, string, replace

I need to add a comma after every two words in a string.

```
String s = "every day every night every minute every second";
```

I want result in this format:

```
String s = "every day, every night, every minute, every second";
```

At first I thought it'll be easy to solve but I'm unable to solve this problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? There are many possible solutions.

Comment: get all spaces and set comma for every seconds spaces.

Comment: This might work: `String result = s.replaceAll("([^ ]+ [^ ]+) ", "$1, ");`

Comment: Thanks @Nulano .This is working perfect. Before I've only tried replacing all empty spaces with comma's but your answer is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks alot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
String result = s.replaceAll("([^ ]+ [^ ]+) ", "$1, ");
```

You can use an online regex tester to see how it works: https://regex101.com/r/9eSRzC/2

EDIT: Alternatively, if you do not wish to use a regex, you can use this code:

```
String s = "every day every night every minute every second";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int last = -1;
while (true) {
    int i = s.indexOf(' ', last+1);
    if (i < 0) break;
    i = s.indexOf(' ', i+1);
    if (i < 0) break;
    sb.append(s.substring(last+1,i)).append(", ");
    last = i;
}
sb.append(s.substring(last+1));
String result = sb.toString();
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use regular expressions this will do the job:

```
String[] strArray = s.split(" ");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i<strArray.length; i++) {
  sb.append(strArray[i]);      
  if(i%2!=0) {
    sb.append(",");
  }
  sb.append(" ");
}
return sb.toString();
```

Comment: Note that this still uses regular expressions in the split call. A better way would be iterating through the characters in the original String and doing the splitting yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "every day every night every minute every second";
    char[] str = s.toCharArray();
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
        if(str[i] == ' '){
            count++;
            if(count%2 == 0){
                str[i] = ',';
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(new String(str));
```

Comment: This has a problem of removing the space and replacing it with a comma. (There should be a space after the commas - see the example.)